# Save Array to MySQL Field

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook-graph-api

im fetching from facebooks opengraph all musik interests of a user and want to compare these later with the interests of another user. Is there a smart way to save those information to a mysql database?

Comment: By normalizing the structure of your database

Comment: @MarkBaker you have a short description of how or a example for me?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization - Learn to normalize, and a database will be your bestest ever friend for life, don't normalize and the database will be cruel and spiteful and place every obstacle in your way to hurt you

Answer (score 0):

Serialize data before saving in DB.

```
 insert into YourTable (data_source_id,data) values (".$source_id.",'".serialize($YourData)."');
```

Comment: This shoul really be a comment

Comment: Ok,i fixed. now(), better?

Comment: Except serialization isn't a good answer when OP decides they want to search for all users who like Jazz.... that's when proper database normalization is a better option

Comment: I agree for this if he want to compare this in real time. I noticed that he wrote that he want to "and want to compare these later". I understood he wanted just to collect some data at this time. For compare serialization is not good option.

Comment: The thing is i want to search for matches in interests, in the upper example musik. Some users like 200 musicians others only 10 and i want to compare those two datasets for eventual matches, prefiltered by device location and radius.

Comment: Which is precisely why normalizing the data will be better for doing such searches than serialization

Comment: misunderstood. I agree with Mark. In this case: First prepare DB structure/ normalize data. Serialization will not solve Your Problem.